# Galen framework clarifications for automation

Tags: ui-automation

How to verify form elements like text with disappearing text in 'On-focus' field, out of focus fields? Also how to use javascripts and spec file together for testing in galen framework?

Is there any other framework for UI automation apart from Galen to perform styleguide testing?

Answer (score 0):

Besides Galen you can use [Applitools](https://applitools.com), but if you need more that 25 visual validations per week and more than one concurrent run, you have to pay.

For what you want to achieve you can use the [Galen Javascript API](http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-javascript-api/).